# Click query never work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a javascript script that work like bookmark. After allot of code i need to click in one of the divs I got but i can't get it. If I put mouseover it works but no with click

I am using query

js:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
  $j('<div></div>').prependTo($j(this)).attr('id', 'shadow').css({
                'height': '220px',
                'width': '220px',
                'background-color': 'black',
                'position': 'absolute',
                'top': 0,
                'left': 0,
                'opacity': 0.4,
                'cursor': 'pointer'
            }).click(function() { //this dons't work i try to put apart
                                   //But if I put bind('mouseover' it works
                alert('a');
                //...more stuff

            });
```

In my HTML code its get like this:

```
<div id="div0" class="div" style="position: relative; ">
     <div id="shadow" style="height: 220px; width: 220px; background-color: black; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 0.4; cursor: pointer; "></div>
     <img class="select" id="select0" src="url..." onclick="alert('aaa')">
     <img src="url..." class="img" id="img0" height="62" width="220" style="margin-top:79px"></div>
</div>
```

I put an alert directly to the image and it doesn't work neither

Thanks for all the help

Comment: @mesiesta var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: THat wasn't the question. The question is, since this is a "snippet" of code, it's not showing what "this" is. As a standalone piece of code, it is nothing.

Comment: Sorry about that $(this) = $('.div')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you've setup a shortcut for jQuery to be $j, I've created a sample jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TxKPD/

```
 $('<div></div>').prependTo('body').attr('id', 'shadow').css({
            'height': '220px',
            'width': '220px',
            'background-color': 'black',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': 0,
            'left': 0,
            'opacity': 0.4,
            'cursor': 'pointer'
        }).click(function() { //this dons't work i try to put apart
                               //But if I put bind('mouseover' it works
            alert('a');
            //...more stuff

        });
```

Since it wasn't clear what $(this) was in your query i simply appended your element to the body. Everything is working with the click handler. So that leaves the question, what is triggering your script and what is $(this) ?

Comment: Sorry about that $(this) = $('.div'). I know it works perfect, but why with click it doesn't work and with mouseover it works perfectly

Comment: Ok, but what event is triggering the "prependTo". $(this) can only represent what ever is triggering the prependTo. Are you trying to call this from a onReady? Or are you trying to call this from something else?

Comment: This code runs in bookmark so it need to be ready the webpage. before i have insertAfter($(this)); but i change to this

Comment: Is there a public URL for the full page? Can you edit your question to include more of the script that your using to make the prependTo call?

Comment: Hi splash sorry its a really secret project but I already solved it in (this) the parent of shadow I have .mouseOver to appear the shadow . I substitude for mouse leave & mouseOver and it works perfectly better than it was :) thanks for everything

Answer (score 1):

You're missing something or looking in the wrong place. This code as it's presented is fine. See the proof:

http://jsfiddle.net/H9vzM/

Note: I don't know the context of "this" from your code sample, so I manually select an existing "placeholder" div instead.

Comment: Yes all the code it parts works pretty good :S but maybe i don't know another layer its getting the click. I can't give more code in here :S